# this.id vs. $(this).attr('id')

Tags: jquery

Is

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

the same as:

```
this.id
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, they're not exactly the same.

They'll both return the element's ID, but if the element has no ID, then `this.id` will return a blank string while `$(this).attr("id")` will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

Almost (see [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597317/this-id-vs-this-attrid/5597454#5597454)).

jQuery abstracts away attribute getting, but it isn't always the most terse option.

It is however shorter than `getAttribute('id')`.

Answer (score 2):

Same result, but this.id is much faster as it doesn't require all the jQuery stuff around it. You will also get different results if that item doesn't have an id.