# Javascript button ID selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to Javascript, seems I'm missing something simple here. I just want to return the ID of the button I am clicking but instead I'm getting "undefined."

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" id="{{user.get('name')}}">
    <button class="btn" id="voteup">^^</button>
    <h4>{{user.get('vote')}}</h4>
    <button class="btn" id="votedown">vv</button>    
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(".btn").click(function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
)};
```

Comment: Something weird is going on here

This runs:
alert("hello");

but this doesn't:

$(document).ready(function() {
       alert("hello");
  )};

Comment: Are you sure that you've added jQuery to the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });

});
```

Comment: Misread his code in my hurry, thought I saw a return there somewhere. Changed to alert.

Comment: That actually doesn't run at all, no alert or anything.

Comment: You have a `)};` closing of `doc ready` which is wrong, that should be  this `});`

Answer (score 4):

You mixed up the things. [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) accepts the handler function which is executed when the DOM tree is fully loaded. The correct solution is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ha  you just updated never mind. I just saw that anyway great answer.

Comment: @Jai Yep, I was also looking at the code and *feeling* that something is wrong. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @asolberg You're welcome... but I was quicker according to post time `;)`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can read the `id` attribute like this:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: This is false. `this.id` is much faster way.

Comment: They behave differently, returning different values if no id is present, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597317/this-id-vs-this-attrid. Plus they're not that different in speed, see: http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-vs-attr-id

Comment: Well, firstly, your perf is wrong, since it should be `$('#testDiv span')[0].id`. Then, that is not the real case. The real case is here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-id-vs-attr-id/2. And the difference is great.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to bind click listener is

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".btn",function(e){
          alert($(this).prop("id"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not to use `this.id`? This is absolutely the same but faster.

Comment: @VisioN Just in case, if there's need to get and change `id` of element. Yes, `this.id` is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.btn').live('click', function(){
    var id = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
  });
});
```

Try it and tell us if worked or not (:

Comment: Don't use `live`, it is deprecated.

Comment: @VisioN it depends on which version of jQuery you're working on. The principle is almost the same as using on. Is just that I'm used to work with live (since I'm still working with old versions of jQuery for some legacy projects).

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you have error in your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(".btn").click(function() { //<----here in doc ready handler
   var id = this.id;
   alert(id);
)}; //<---------------closing of the handler
```

this should be changed to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn").click(function() {
      var id = this.id;
      alert(id);
   });
});
```