# Get ID of existing same class name element created dynamically

Tags: jquery, attributes

I already have some href anchors in my DOM like this:-

```
    <div id="outermenu">
        <a href="#" id="uniqueid1" class="myclassone">link</a>
        <a href="#" id="uniqueid2" class="myclasstwo">link</a>
    </div>
```

I am using jQuery to insert more href anchors, all of which use the same class name of only one other element on the page, so there will be two instances of the href with class "myclassone", only one of these will have the id "uniqueid1".

What I am looking to do when the dynamically inserted anchor elements are added to the DOM via another click method, find the anchors with the same class name and get the unique id attribute for each corresponding element with the same class name and print this in a div with id 'box'.

I have tried the following, to no avail.

```
$('this').each(function () {
    var anchorid = this.id;
    $("#box").html(anchorid);
});
```

Basically, how can I traverse through the DOM and find an elements ID inside the "outerid" div ID which has the same class name as a newly created element and subsequently display the elements ID?

Update: Thanks for the replies. I failed to mention that I am using this within the jquery autocomplete plugin by devbridge, which the docs state $this is bound to the input element.

I have therefore set up the autocomplete plugin like so:-

```
   var searchwordss = [
      { value: 'First Word', data: 'myclassone' }, 
....
```

Then using the data value to output:-

```
    var searchresults = '<a href="#" class="' + suggestion.data + '">Click here see more ' + suggestion.value + ' articles.</a>';
    $('#box').html(searchresults);
```

This generates:-
     Click here see more First Word articles.

I therefore need to get the ID for another purpose, the ID of the anchor element which already exists in the DOM and has class "myclassone" - bearing in mind this class name will change depending on the autocomplete search word selected. So, in my HTML example, $this is bound to "outermenu".

Comment: If I were you I'd avoid this problem altogether, instead of creating IDs, keep references to the elements you own and put sequential elements in an array (or nodelist), then you can access them by index.

Comment: its $(this) and not $('this'), second its $(this).id and not this.id

Comment: .attr("id") is better

Comment: what about .find('.myclassone').attr('id'); ?

Comment: [Vanilla-js is better](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: this.id is perfectly fine @Ahmad

Comment: @JayBlanchard for second one works, what about his first syntax issue?

Comment: Using `this.id` is more correct than using `$(this).attr("id")`, the latter demonstrates lack of basic understanding of the DOM API. You have an element with an ID property so you just ask for it, you don't wrap it in a jQuery object constructor, then access it as an attribute with strings. @nicolallias Ahmad

Comment: @nicolallias are you trolling? please tell me you are trolling.

Comment: @Ahmad I think his first syntax issue is because he is using pseudo-code - he doesn't know what 'this' should be.

Comment: Hey dudes, I believe that somebody of you guys gave me a -1 on my answer. could you please look at the updated answer and see if it is realy worth -1 ?? I think my answer is correct... Thanks

Comment: @Luke why would you assume that any of us would give you -1 on your answer? This question was read by 27 people (probably more when you read this comment).  It is just as likely that one of those other 23 people did not like your answer so they downvoted it. Not me anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum its not necessarily more correct, they're both the same, $(this) simply wraps the this object to allow jquery methods call on it, and since the user is using jquery and not plain javascript then better he sticks with jquery style instead of using a different on each line.

Comment: I have updated the OP, because I failed to mention $this is bound to the autocomplete item.

Comment: Wrapping the id value in a jQuery object would serve no purpose at this point @Ahmad since we are just getting the value of that id and assigning it to a variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597317/this-id-vs-this-attrid

Answer (score 1):

To answer this in the OP's question -

> What I am looking to do when the dynamically inserted anchor elements are added to the DOM via another click method, find the anchors with the same class name and get the unique id attribute for each corresponding element with the same class name and print this in a div with id 'box'.

```
$('#add').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('a').each(function() {
        if( $(this).hasClass('myclassone') ) {
            $('#box').append(this.id);
        }
    });
});
```

This can be seen in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/3473s/ All that is left to do is calculate a unique id and add the new element to the page.

Comment: why not use directly $('a.myclassone') instead the if clause?

Comment: You could, more than one way to skin a cat. It was just my train of thought while developing the fiddle.

Comment: This displays the id as "outermenu", I need to get the "id" of the a href element within the outermenu div which has the same class name. Thanks!

Comment: I just ran this and it displays the id as "uniqueid1". There is not way that this code could return "outermenu" as div's are not targeted during the click function.

Answer (score 0):

i assume your html tags like...

```
<div id="outermenu">
        <a href="#" id="uniqueid1" class="myclassone">link</a>
        <a href="#" id="uniqueid2" class="myclasstwo">link</a>

        <a href="#" id="uniqueid3" class="myclassone">link</a>
        <a href="#" id="uniqueid4" class="myclasstwo">link</a>


    </div>

<div id="box">

</div>
```

Your javascript :

```
$.each($("a"), function(i,v) {
    var theTag = v.tagName;
    var theElement = $(v);
    var theValue = theElement.val();
      $("#box").html(v.id);
});
```

see fiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/VLwy6/1/

Answer (score 0):

> find the anchors with the same class name and get the unique id
>   attribute for each corresponding element with the same class name and
>   print this in a div with id 'box'.

Try this:

```
$('a.className').each(function(){
    $('#box').append(this.id);
})
```

Note that html() replace the text inside the box, so u wont see previous IDs. 
Use append() instead.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wWr4P/)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `[id]` selector which gives you an element, that has at least the ID attribute

```
$("[id].myclassone")
```

will give you an element with the class myclassone that has the id attribute.

So if you have a reference to an element that has a specific class, and you want an other element that has the same class name but also the ID attribute you can do

```
$("[id]." + this.className))
```

so `this` is the raw reference to the DOM Element (Anchor). If you have a jQuery Reference, you need to use `.get()` to get the real DOM Element Reference. Then you can get the `className` property.
You can also use `$(this).attr("class")`.

An exact example would be

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    var className = this.className;
    var id = $("[id]." + className).attr("id");
    $("#box").append("<p>" + id + "</p>");
});
```