# $(this).prop('property') vs. this.property

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given jQuery's philosophy of ***write less, do more***, I'm always surprised when I see this:

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

… instead of this:

```
this.checked
```

Looking at the latest jQuery source, `prop()` provides convenience for these two *gotchas*:

1. `$(elem).prop('for')` is equivalent to `elem.htmlFor`.
2. `$(elem).prop('class')` is equivalent to `elem.className`.

It also normalizes `tabIndex` to:

- 0 for tabbable elements without a tab index.

  -1 for non-tabbable elements.

`prop()` is certainly useful for setting properties for multiple elements at once, and for chaining properties on a single element.

But is there any advantage (other than idiomatic) to use `prop()` to set or retrieve a single property on a single element except when normalizing `tabIndex` – specifically when you have a reference to the element (such as `this` in a callback)?

Comment: No, there's no advantage. It's convenient when the *only* thing you've got is already a jQuery object, but making a new jQuery object just so that `.prop()` can be called is silly.

Comment: You can chain jq methods by using .prop()

Comment: @px5x2 — Not when reading a value from it as per this example.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy.  I know this risks being an "opinionated" question, but I often see code like `$(this).prop('checked')` from posters with high rep, so I wondered if I was missing something.

Comment: @Quentin y sure in this case prop would be terminating op.

Comment: I like this thread - not sure it requires an answer, but you illustrate one of the many reasons I only use 5% as much of the jQuery lib as I did 5 years ago. The vanilla approach even makes total sense with basic js types, e.g. the checked property on `document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]')` will give me a boolean since it's finding a checkbox, but `document.querySelector('div')` will be undefined.

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Sometimes that form is used for consistency with the rest of the code, or to not confuse newbies, or simply wasn't edited when copying code from a question to an answer. Despite better knowledge.

Comment: jQuery does some corrections for certain properties, e.g. `src` and `href` in IE, `tabIndex` , ...

Comment: @t.niese, the only correction I see in the source code for `prop()` is for normalizing `tabIndex`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock —jQuery 2 dropped support for old-IE. Maybe those normalisations are in jQuery 1 and you are looking at 2?

Comment: @Quentin, I see the same code in https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js.  Search for "propFix:".

Comment: related: [`this.id` vs. `$(this).attr('id')`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5597317/1048572) and [`this.href` vs `$(this).attr('href')`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6977049/1048572)

Comment: @t.niese, I consider `for` and `class` to be conveniences rather than normalizations.  I don't see anything in the source that normalizes `selected`, `scrollTop`, or `scrollLeft` as far as the `prop()` method is concerned.

Comment: @RickHitchcock yes sorry should have taken more time to look at it. But anyway, the last point is still true. jQuery was started when there where many differences between the browsers. The idea ist to have an abstraction layer  to run code in an _uncontrolled_ environment like a browser, that allows to fix bugs a  central point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.prop` as a getter has no real advantage, in fact, it is less performant than directly accessing the property.

The real utility of `.prop` is when used as a setter.

If you read the [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2), there is 3 way of setting something with `.prop`.

---

## .prop(prop, value)

The first way has no advantage for a single element(except maybe if there is compatibility issue).

In fact `this.check = true;` is the same as `$(this).prop('checked', true)`, but faster.

If you have a set of element though, there is an advantage. You don't have to manually loop all elements, jQuery does it for you.

---

## .prop({prop : value[, prop : value, ...]});

The second way is useful when you have multiple properties to change. Instead of listing every properties you want to change like that :

```
this.prop1=true;
this.prop2=true;
this.prop3=true;
this.prop4=true;
```

You can pass an object like that :

```
$(this).prop({
    prop1 : true,
    prop2 : true,
    prop3 : true,
    prop4 : true
});
```

---

## .prop(prop, callback)

The third way is in my opinion my favorite one. Using a callback function allow you to set every element individually on a set of condition. The callback receive 2 arguments: the index and the old value.

A good example of the use of a function is to reverse the state of every checkbox:

```
$('checkbox').prop('checked', function(_, old){
    return !old;
});
```

Comment: `prop` as a getter has the advantage of working on every jQuery collection, especially empty and dynamically selected ones. Of course it's pointless on `$(this)` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Ahah yeah, I didn't think it was a *real* advantage, but you're right.

Comment: This seems definitive, and the `callback` method absolutely provides an advantage in some situations.  Accepted, thanks.