# Get ID of TD on click of table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery function where,when the table is clicked, I need to know the ID of the table cell that was clicked. Here is my  [JS Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/x7czw6au/1/)  And here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#board", function(e) {
    var data = $(this).find('td').attr('id');
    alert (data);
});
```

Even though this is giving me an ID, it keeps giving me the ID of the first cell. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is requirement to call `alert` for each `id` for each `td` element within clicked `tr` element ?

Comment: @guest271314 I alert() to make sure the jQuery actually saved the right info to var data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "#board td", function(e) {
     var data = $(this).attr('id');
     alert (data);
});
```

Target cell, rather than table...

Comment: fwiw, can use `this.id` instead of calling jQuery twice for `$(this).attr('id');` , return same result https://jsfiddle.net/x7czw6au/3/

Comment: Absolutely, more about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597317/this-id-vs-this-attrid

Comment: Oh good lord I am too slow at this. Thanks nevermind for this code and thanks guest271314 for bringing to my attention that "#board td" means find the td of your table :P better hit the books a little more!